# Passing parameters between JSF pages

Tags: jsf

actually I use h:link with h:param to pass parameters from one page to another.

The problem is that so the parameters come in the url too and in some cases I don't want it (the page should not be bookmarkable).

How can I do? What should I use?

Thank you in advance
Francesco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `h:commandLink` instead of `h:link`. Your page invocation will be done through a `POST` command instead of a `GET` command. Hence, parameter will not show up in URL.

Here's is an example I got from [here](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html#Table4_17):

```
<h:commandLink>
    <h:outputText value="welcome"/>
    <f:param name="outcome" value="welcome"/>
</h:commandLink>
```